# Sublime 3 - Theme is not applied to the Side Bar/Console

Tags: console, sublimetext3, sidebar

I just switched over to *Sublime 3*, using it as a my current text editor.  I downloaded the theme "Coffee Dark Roast" (which I think looks pretty slick) from GitHub and the theme appears to be working just fine except for the fact that it is not being applied to the **Side Bar** that shows open files.  Also, the theme is not being applied to the **Console** at the bottom of the screen either.

Does anyone have a solution, or reason as to why the theme is not working for the **Side Bar** and **Console**?

MacBook Pro OS X 10.9.5

Comment: Have you restarted Sublime completely? This is necessary to theme all elements. Also, do you know that the theme applies to the side bar and console? Some don't...

Comment: @MattDMo I have restarted Sublime completely, and yes the theme should apply to the side bad/console.

Answer (score -1):

Check your user preferences and make sure that you don't have another sidebar theme present. This is usually the case.

Comment: I checked all user preferences/re-installed/changed themes. Did not work.